# XML with sub nodes to csv format using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, export-to-csv

I need some help with converting XML with child nodes to csv file.

Here's my XML:

```
<Main>
  <root>
    <Name>Sample name1</Name>
    <StreetAddress>Sample Address1</StreetAddress>
    <Service>
      <Type>Outlet</Type>
      <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
      <Openweekday>Closed</Openweekday>
    </Service>
    <Service>
      <Type>Mall</Type>
      <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
      <Openweekday>Closed</Openweekday>
      </Service>
  </root>
  <root>
    <Name>Sample name2</Name>
    <StreetAddress>Sample Address2</StreetAddress>
    <Service>
      <Type>Shop</Type>
      <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
      <Openweekday>Closed</Openweekday>
    </Service>
</Main>
```

Expected CSV Result:

```
Name,StreetAddress,Type,PhoneNumber,OpenweekDay,Type,PhoneNumber,OpenweekDay
Sample name1,Sample Address1,Outlet,,Closed,Mall,,Closed
Sample name2,Sample Address2,Shop,,Closed
```

Tried this code I got from MSDN. But it throws a null exception -

```
XElement custOrd = XElement.Load("xxx.xml");
    string csv =
        (from el in custOrd.Element("Main").Elements("root")
         select
             String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}",
                 (string)el.Attribute("Name"),
                 (string)el.Element("StreetAddress"),
                 (string)el.Element("Service").Element("Type"),
                 (string)el.Element("Service").Element("PhoneNumber"),
                 (string)el.Element("Service").Element("Openweekday"),
                 (string)el.Element("Service").Element("Type"),
                 (string)el.Element("Service").Element("PhoneNumber"),
                 (string)el.Element("Service").Element("Openweekday"),
                 Environment.NewLine
             )
        )
        .Aggregate(
            new StringBuilder(),
            (sb, s) => sb.Append(s),
            sb => sb.ToString()
        );
    Console.WriteLine(csv);
```

let me know how to manage nulls within linq.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @paqogomez - How do I manage null inside the linq for each element?  How do I handle when the service node is missing? I am new to linq.

Comment: @paqogomez - The duplicate reference post you added does not answer my question? Can you remove it so others can help me out?

Comment: No one sees that except you, though others get to vote on if its truly a duplicate or not.  So far, only one other agrees with me.  As for your question, it seems to me that inline if statements would fix your problem.  Something like `el.Element("Service").Element("PhoneNumber") == null ? "" : el.Element("Service").Element("PhoneNumber");`

Comment: And that inline statement is covered very well in the duplicate link that I provided.

Comment: @CoderofCode casting null to string is fine : `var test = (string)null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mention on loading or parsing the xml, main is already referenced, so your starting point should be root. 
This will give you the structure you are looking for.

```
        XElement dataSet1Tree = XElement.Parse(xml);
        var dataSet1List = dataSet1Tree.Elements().Select(
        root => new
        {
            Name = (string)root.Element("Name"),
            StreetAddress = (string)root.Element("StreetAddress"),
            Service = root.Elements("Service")
                .Select(service => new
                {
                    Type = (string)service.Element("Type"),
                    PhoneNumber = (string)service.Element("PhoneNumber"),
                    OpenWeekDay = (string)service.Element("Openweekday")
                })

        }).SelectMany(root => root.Service, (root, service) => new
        {
            Name = root.Name, 
            StreetAddress = root.StreetAddress , 
            Type = service.Type, 
            PhoneNumber = service.PhoneNumber,
            OpenWeekDay = service.OpenWeekDay
        }).Aggregate("",(sb,s)=> sb +=string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}",
                                                    s.Name,
                                                    s.StreetAddress,
                                                    s.Type,
                                                    s.PhoneNumber, 
                                                    s.OpenWeekDay)+"\r\n");

Console.WriteLine(dataSet1List);
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that `custOrd` it self already references `<Main>` so calling `Element("Main")` on `custOrd` will return `null`, and calling `Elements("root")` on `null` will definitely trigger null reference exception.

To fix that problem, you can either change `custOrd` to an `XDocument` type :

```
XDocument custOrd = XDocument.Load("xxx.xml");
```

...or simply remove `.Element("Main")` call :

```
XElement custOrd = XElement.Load("xxx.xml");
string csv =
        (from el in custOrd.Elements("root")
        ......
        ......
```

Casting `null` to string is safe, but in case there any `<root>` without child element `<service>` your code will throw null reference exception again.